# Parental control: interrupting apps sent over the network to direct child to other app or external event

Tags: applications, accessibility, parental-control

Phones can be used to interrupt children.

The common scenario, is, that the child wants to use the phone to understand something or to do something, but the parent wants to interrupt the child to get them to do or learn something else.

For example, they may want them to learn a language, or learn about timetables, timing, preparing and being on time, or about when what will happen and how to plan and be aware of when the parent and child will go to which event, when it will happen, who will be there, explain the concept of time and future, perhaps, even on time.

In order to do this, the parent, may elicit to use special apps for this (how these apps would be designed, this, I address in a separate post).

This post is about whether Android should be designed with interruption apps, special apps used to interrupt the user, explain, visually, what the interruption is about (a parent could, for example, also, very practical, in my opinion, send an interrupt to eat, interrupt, which would display an image of a family eating in front of the phone, as an overlay, and this could be sent from the parent phone to the child phone). This, would make unnecessary grabbing the phone out of the child's hands and getting them to sit at the table in a more clumsy manner. It would just be nice to have the overlay app.

So we need:

- apps to direct us to other apps (hopefully, these, would be well designed (or the child experience would be terrible and they would regret it).
- apps to direct the child to events external to the phone

The interruption overlay, or interruption overlay with button (in case we must direct the child to a different app), must be such, that they can be taken off by the parent from the parent phone to the child phone (in case the child cries, or cries excessively).

Is this possible in Android?

Is anyone willing to develop this?

Would, this, even (be helpful).

Thank you for your support.

Has this been developed?

Thanks.